# python netsnmp with twisted

Tags: python, network-programming, twisted, snmp

I am trying to find if Python's [netsnmp](https://net-snmp.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/net-snmp/trunk/net-snmp/python/README) binding can be made async using [twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/)? If anyone has an example, that would be helpful. My goal here is to see if I can use Python's netsnmp binding in a asyn manner to listen on trap, send SNMP get request, etc.

Answer (score -1):

So far i have found [pynetsnmp](https://github.com/zenoss/pynetsnmp) written by zenoss which is pretty outdated. Not sure if there are any newer libraries or if twisted is coming with their own SNMP library?

Answer (score -1):

Did you check pysnmp out? The library support twisted. http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/v3arch/twisted/contents.html

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from pysnmp.entity import engine, config
from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413 import cmdrsp, context
from pysnmp.carrier.twisted.dgram import udp

snmpEngine = engine.SnmpEngine()

config.addTransport(
    snmpEngine,
    udp.domainName,
    udp.UdpTwistedTransport().openServerMode(('127.0.0.1', 161))
)

config.addV1System(snmpEngine, 'my-read-area', 'public')
config.addV1System(snmpEngine, 'my-write-area', 'private')


config.addVacmUser(snmpEngine, 1, 'my-read-area', 'noAuthNoPriv', (1, 3, 6, 1, 2, 1))
config.addVacmUser(snmpEngine, 1, 'my-write-area', 'noAuthNoPriv', (1, 3, 6, 1, 2, 1), (1, 3, 6, 1, 2, 1))

snmpContext = context.SnmpContext(snmpEngine)

cmdrsp.GetCommandResponder(snmpEngine, snmpContext)
cmdrsp.SetCommandResponder(snmpEngine, snmpContext)
cmdrsp.NextCommandResponder(snmpEngine, snmpContext)

reactor.run()
```

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Answer (score -2):

http://twistedsnmp.sourceforge.net is an implementation of just that.

Comment: This is binding with pysnmp, not netsnmp